# Can you combine javascript et base url w/ change window location?

Tags: javascript, function

I have two separate functions that I'd like to ask if I can combine?  The first is to get the base URL and the second is to parse the base URL and change the window location. I'm not getting errors running this as is, but it's not producing the results I'm looking for. I'm trying to modify the base URL depending on which environment I'm working in (local, dev, test, stage, production). Any input would be greatly appreciated!

```
<script>
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href=location.href
// parser.hostname = "d-auth.123.com"
var env = parser.hostname.split("-")[0]
// env = "d"
var baseurl;
switch (env) {
case "l":
    baseurl = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname;
    break;
case "d":
    baseurl = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname;
    break;
case "t":
    baseurl = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname;
    break;
case "s":
    baseurl = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname;
    break;
default:
    baseurl = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname;
}
</script>
<script>
$("body").keydown(function(event) {

if(event.case == "l") { // left
    window.location = "https://l-www.123.com";
}
else if(event.case == "d") { // right
    window.location = "https://d-www.123.com"; 
}
else if(event.case == "t") { // right
    window.location = "https://t-www.123.com"; 
}
else if(event.case == "s") { // right
    window.location = "https://s-www.123.com"; 
}
else if(event.case == "default") { // right
    window.location = "https://www.123.com"; 
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: 1-what do you mean by `left` and `right` ?

2-if your href =  "http://d-auth.123.com/abc"
where do you want to navigate ?

Comment: Those are just developer notes. It's just a reminder where the login fields reside in each environment.

Comment: if your href = "d-auth.123.com/abc"  where do you want to navigate in keydown event ?

Comment: That's what I'm attempting in the second function window.location.  Depending on which environment I'm in I want the base URL to be l-www.123.com, d-www.123.com etc